# Only few users photos syncing to SharePoint 2016 from AD via MIM

Tags: 2016, mim

I have configured MIM SP1 with SharePoint 2016 and it synced user information from AD to UPS in SharePoint 2016.

I checked My site host and under  http://mysite/User%20Photos/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx only few users phots synced not All users.

MIM is installed using Farm account on SharePoint 2016 server and on My site web application I also gave full permission to farm account via below script:

```
$userOrGroup = "am\app-dev-farm" 
 $displayName = "Farm Account"
 $WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mysite"
 $policy = $WebApp.Policies.Add($userOrGroup, $displayName) 
 $policyRole = $webApp.PolicyRoles.GetSpecialRole([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPolicyRoleType]::FullControl) 
 $policy.PolicyRoleBindings.Add($policyRole) 
 $webApp.Update()
```

---

I ran full sync but still showing few user photos not all users.

Please help.

Comment: One more information:

In MIM for the ADMA, I checked some users metaverse object properties and found that in "Attribute Flow Rules" thumbnail photo attribute initial value is blank but some users this attribute has binary value and these users have their photos in SharePoint UPS.

So some how ADMA is not picking the picture from AD.

Any guess